# Generalization of the geodesic deviation equation to non-geodesics - a missing term

Tags: gravity, differential-geometry, curvature, geodesics

I have been trying to derive the expression in Ex.3.3 of Straumann's book for the evolution of the separation vector
between neighbouring curves that are not necessarily geodesic.

The claim is that, for $u$ - the tangent vector field, $a=\nabla_{u}u$ its acceleration and $n$ - the separation vector ($n=v+g(u,v)u$, where $v$ was the vector field traversing the geodesic congruence) the following evolution equation holds:

\begin{equation}
\nabla_{u}\nabla_{u}n = R(\cdot,u,u,n) + g(a,n)a + (\nabla_{n}a)_{\perp}
\end{equation}
where $\perp$ indicates the projection onto the subspace orthogonal to $u$, i.e. $X_{\perp} = X + g(X,u)u$.

I have been able to recover the first two terms on the RHS, but I cannot seem to recover the third one fully.

What this would require is the
\begin{equation}
g(\nabla_{n}a,u)\, u = \nabla_{u}(g(u,n))\, a + \nabla_u(g(a,n))\,u
\end{equation}
but does not seem to follow at all.
Has anybody ever tackled this exercise? I know it can be found in the book by Hawking and Ellis, but I am interested in following similar steps to Straumann in that regard, i.e. preferably without index notation.

Comment: you’re misunderstanding the exercise itself. You’re supposed to consider the Fermi-acceleration $F_uF_un$, not the covariant acceleration $\nabla_u\nabla_un$ of the separation vector field.

Comment: I can't believe I hadn't added the pieces together, from even the notational point of view no less. Thanks a lot